# Use Mathematica to calculate the area enclosed between two curves

Tags: functions, programming

use mathematica

Hence, calculate the exact area enclosed by these curves using *Mathematica*.
$f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^5 - 2 x^3 - 3 x$

i have got the graph...now I'm stuck with finding the area

Comment: the interval is not given...

Comment: im also unable to figure out from the graph

Answer (score 13):

Here is a different approach based on the awesome new `Region` functions:

```
f[x_] := x^3
g[x_] := x^5 - 2 x^3 - 3 x
```

We solve for the intersections:

```
sol = x /. NSolve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals]
```

> {-1.94712297, 0, 1.94712297}

**Edit**

Here are the regions of interest:

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[g[x] > y && f[x] < y, {{x, -1.94712297, 0}, y}];
r2 = ImplicitRegion[g[x] < y && f[x] > y, {{x, 0, 1.94712297}, y}];
```

And the area is simply:

```
Area @ RegionUnion[r1, r2]
```

> 14.7695075

We can visualize the region to be sure:

```
RegionPlot[{r1, r2}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-8, 8}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Regarding all solutions using `NSolve`, numeric intermediate solutions and getting numeric area: `Solve` works fine, and produces a `Root` object. All values in this problem can be maintained in abstract, precise form - either `Root`, or converted to radicals using `ToRadicals`. And of course, `FullSimplify` often cleans up overly complicated radicals.

Comment: @kirma, I realize that `Solve` works fine and gives the exact value, that was what I used first. I just wanted to use `NSolve` to keep things simple and convey the idea which is the important thing here.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what the plot looks like:

```
f[x_] := x^3
g[x_] := x^5 - 2 x^3 - 3 x

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You first solve for the intersections:

```
sol = x /. NSolve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals]

{-1.94712297, 0, 1.94712297}
```

Now you can find the area by integrating the difference between the curves in the intervals obtained:

```
Integrate[g[x] - f[x], {x, sol[[1]], sol[[2]]}]
```

> 7.38475373

Same goes for the interval from $0$ to $1.9471$, in this region $f(x) > g(x)$

```
Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, sol[[2]], sol[[3]]}]
```

> 7.38475373

So the total area is just $2(7.38475373)$

> 14.7695075

From the graph it's obvious both functions are symmetric and we could have just found the area in one region and multiplied by $2$.

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_] := x^3
g[x_] := x^5 - 2 x^3 - 3 x
sol = Partition[x /. NSolve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals], 2, 1]
Tr@(Abs@Integrate[g[x] - f[x], {x, Sequence @@ #}] & /@ sol)

(*14.7695*)
```

Comment: Is there an obfuscated Mathematica contest?? :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure ya know: "your programming style mirrors your mind"

Answer (score 5):

The exact area - i.e. not a numerical approximation - can be obtained as follows:

```
f[x_] := x^3;
g[x_] := x^5 - 2 x^3 - 3 x;
```

Find the points on the real axis where `f[x]` and `g[x]` intersect.

```
sol = Solve[f[x] == g[x], x, Reals]

(* {{x -> 0}, {x -> Root[-3 - 3 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 1]}, {x -> Root[-3 - 3 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]}} *)
```

Compute the area enclosed by integrating `Abs[f[x] - g[x]]` between the end points.

```
area = Integrate[Abs[f[x] - g[x]], {x, x /. sol[[2]], x /. sol[[3]]}] // FullSimplify

(* 1/4 (27 + 7 Sqrt[21]) *)
```

Compute a numerical approximation to the enclosed area.

```
N[area]

(* 14.7695 *)
```