# Find the area between the curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

`x = 0`, `x = 4`, `y = 2e^3x`, `y = e^3x + e^9`

I have tried to solve this problem and can’t get it right. You need to find the area between the curves with these constraints. I’d appreciate any help thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Mathematica to calculate the area enclosed between two curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58581/use-mathematica-to-calculate-the-area-enclosed-between-two-curves)

Answer (score 6):

```
funcs = {2 E^(3 x), E^(3 x) + E^9};
```

The curves intersect at

```
pt = {x, funcs[[1]]} /. Solve[Equal @@ funcs && 0 < x < 4, x][[1]]

(* {3, 2 E^9} *)

Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 4},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.5, .5}],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[pt]},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

Using integration to calculate the area

```
area = Integrate[Abs[Subtract @@ funcs], {x, 0, 4}]

(* 1/3 (1 + 4 E^9 + E^12) *)
```

Comparing with results using regions

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[((Less @@ Insert[funcs, y, 2]) && 
      0 < x < 3) || ((Greater @@ Insert[funcs, y, 2]) && 3 < x < 4), 
    {x, y}];

area == Area@rgn

(* True *)
```

Or

```
area == RegionMeasure@rgn

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use integrate to find the area under the curve and then subtract the difference.

```
y1 = 2 Exp[3 x];
y2 = Exp[3 x] + Exp[9];
x0 = x /. First@Solve[y1 == y2, x, Reals];
Plot[{Callout[y1, "y1", Scaled[0.5]], 
  Callout[y2, "y2", Scaled[0.25]]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.025], Point[{x0, y1 /. x -> x0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
A1=Integrate[y2,{x,0,x0}]-Integrate[y1,{x,0,x0}]//N
A2=Integrate[y1,{x,x0,4}]-Integrate[y2,{x,x0,4}]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So area is

```
area=A1+A2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or just use `Abs` in the above, since we do not care about the sign

```
A1=Abs[Integrate[y1,{x,0,x0}]-Integrate[y2,{x,0,x0}]];
A2=Abs[Integrate[y1,{x,x0,4}]-Integrate[y2,{x,x0,4}]];
area = A1 + A2
```